# Is there something like a Virtual Environment for Arduino?

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm using Arduino IDE for a variety of projects.

The libraries and boards used in different projects are different and I would like to have a customized environment for each project.

Eg: In a project involving an Arduino, I don't want all the ESP boards or Adafruit libraries that I might use on another project.

Python has something called Virtual Environments, where you can switch between environments and have a different setup of libraries and configurations for each project.

Is there something like this I can configure for Arduino?

Comment: Development environment like [PlatformIO](https://platformio.org) allow you to have your dependency libraries installed on per-project basis. It can be installed on Atom Editor or VSCode as a plug-in.

Comment: in Arduino IDE you can set the sketchbook folder

Comment: you can use GIT; all the config is "rest"ful; lives in files.

Comment: Has someone ever tried to run the Arduino-cli in a docker container? Just one crazy thought

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but in Arduino IDE no such functionality as virtual enviroment. To add your own version of libraries to each projects you may only add it (libraries) directly to a project dir.

Comment: in Arduino IDE you can select the sketchbook folder. it contains the sketches, libraries, custom hardware specs. that is a much cleaner solution then adding libraries to sketch.